# Check if session users is admin or simple

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

i want to make if clause for button. If admin is logged in it will shown otherwise not.

```
if($this->Session->User['role'] == 'admin') {
    echo
    '<li> <a href="/VAG/dashboard"><ul class="pull-right">Admin skiltis</ul></a></li>';
}
```

I can't get that role from session and compare if it admin or not..

Comment: Have you started a session, check it.

Comment: I tried to print session and looks like it started.

Comment: If so, see if you sated `User['role']` or not before `if($this->Session->User['role'] == 'admin') {`this line.

Comment: Can you show us the `print_r($_SESSION)` ?

Comment: Array ( [Config] => Array ( [userAgent] => 4df452d8263aa05ef9324f37499322b0 [time] => 1401090120 [countdown] => 10 ) [Message] => Array ( ) [Auth] => Array ( [User] => Array ( [id] => 8 [username] => aaaaa [email] => aaa@gmail.com [role] => admin [created] => 2014-05-26 02:43:20 [modified] => 2014-05-26 02:43:20 [status] => 1 ) ) )

Comment: if you are saving User as array in session then you may get this as from session helper in View like $this->Session->read('User.role');

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If value of `print_r($_SESSION);` is something like,

```
Array ( [Config] => Array ( [userAgent] => 4df452d8263aa05ef9324f37499322b0 [time] => 1401090120 [countdown] => 10 ) [Message] => Array ( ) [Auth] => Array ( [User] => Array ( [id] => 8 [username] => aaaaa [email] => aaa@gmail.com [role] => admin [created] => 2014-05-26 02:43:20 [modified] => 2014-05-26 02:43:20 [status] => 1 ) ) )
```

Thae try this code, I think it will work,

```
if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] == 'admin') {
echo
'<li> <a href="/VAG/dashboard"><ul class="pull-right">Admin skiltis</ul></a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']` directly is a bad practice, as depending how the `AuthComponent` is configured, it may not be available.

You should better pass the authenticated user from the controller to the views and then only check his properties:

AppController:

```
$authenticated_user = $this->Auth->user();

if(isset($authenticated_user))
{
    $this->set(compact('authenticated_user'));
}
```

Views:

```
if(isset($authenticated_user) && $authenticated_user['role'] == 'admin'){
    ...
}
```

By the way you should also use the `HtmlHelper` in your views to generate links instead of printing `<a>` tags manually with hardcoded urls to benefit from many Cake features.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a little debug on your code.

First check if your session was started. 
You can do this by executing the command "session_status()" if the result is  "PHP_SESSION_NONE" your session isnt started. You can fix it by putting a "session_start()" before any print was made by your page.

Comment: got an error: Notice (8): A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: All right, your session are OK. You can undo this change.
Print your result of the condition
print_r($this->Session->User['role'])
AND
print_r($this->Session)

Comment: print_r($this->Session->User['role']) - no response,
print_r($this->Session) - thousands of response :D

Comment: and for print_r($this->Session)??